# Does the result of a room match have any meaning?

Tags: pokemon-duel

Up to now, every day one of the daily missions I have had was "*Play 1 Room Match*", so I go to the room matches, create a public room, and have a match. I don't seem to get anything from the match, whether I win or lose. So, I figure that a faster way to get the daily bonus would be to start a match and immediately to forfeit it.

Will this tactic have any implications?

How about a slightly longer version of it - will playing poor intentionally to make the match end faster have any implications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen any consequences of a room match. For the daily quest, you can simply forfeit and you'll get the reward.

Note that there is a special mission (gained after 10 daily quests) that requires you to **win** 3 room matches.